# conda install: The following packages are not available from current channels

Tags: anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I'm trying to install the [hoomd](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/hoomd) package from conda-forge. According to the error message I'm getting, it's "not available from current channels," but conda-forge looks like it's in the list. I've been looking for a solution for quite a while. What might be causing this issue?

```
(base) C:\Users\caleb>conda install -c conda-forge hoomd
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - hoomd

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That package is not available for **win-64** platform. If you must run this package, you'll have to look into options like WSL or Docker to run virtualized/containerized Linux. The authors maintain both [a Singularity image](https://glotzerlab-software.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#quick-start) and [a Docker image](https://glotzerlab-software.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docker.html) with the software.